# Best way to check if a opened file needs to be resolved in perforce (command line)

Tags: perforce, command-prompt

I searched all over the net, but couldn't seem to find an answer.
What is the best way to find if an opened file needs to be resolved before submitting programmatically (using p4 command line tool).
Note: I need to find it before submitting (I know perforce will throw an error on submission, which doesn't suit my needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see unresolved integrations, use

```
p4 resolve -n
```